# ASP.NET MVC formulating the right URL on form GET

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-web-api, http-get

My web-api controller has a GET method to search for domain availability with the route:
api/domain/query/

I would like to construct a form that GETs to this path (by the way do you think POST is better in this case?)

This is crap/bad/wrong, but it is where I am so far (PS I want the form to have an ID).
Model.Name is the domain name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("query", "api/domain", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "domain-query" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Name)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

This will result in: **api/domain/query?Name=test** instead of **api/domain/query/test**

Appreciate your help and I know its a noob question sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here:

1) Do not use GET for your form.  MVC forms in this manner should be POSTed except in special cases.

2) Your `BeginForm` is wrong.  You want the action name and controller name with this overload, but most times you shouldn't have to worry about it.  Again, in most cases you will want

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

like so.

You also don't want to put a "path" for a controller when prompted for a controller.  If your controller name is `AppController` the string for `controller` should simply be `App`.

Looking at this example, I expect you're going to have a bunch of other problems.  Until you wrap your brain around how it's supposed to work, you're going to have quite a few issues to work out.  I strongly suggest walking through the "Nerd Dinner" tutorial for understanding how to write MVC code.